# UIDatePicler = 3 more seconds on load time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

`_datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(70, self.view.frame.size.height -150,250,100);`

I'm using this code under `viewDidLoad` to change the size of a UIDatePicker. It works great but gives me another 3 seconds on load time. I tried using this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    _datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(70, self.view.frame.size.height -150,250,1);

});
```

but I lose all the animation between segues if I do, don't know why. I thought about using another thread in viewDidLoad but I don't know how to do it or if it's possible.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Have you profiled in Instruments to find out what's actually taking the time? `CGRectMake()` is certainly not accounting for the extra time by itself.

Comment: Don't know how. I'll research on it right away

Comment: Added a picture. Hope it helps

Comment: Why are you setting the height of the date picker to be 1?

Comment: You're not supposed to change the size of the date picker. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to have 3 rows instead of 5. Another interesting fact. The view controller with the datepicker takes 4 seconds to load. If I remove the code that changes the height it it takes 1 second to load. If I remove the UIDatePicker completely from my view controller using the Interface Builder that view controller load instantly.

Comment: An obvious work around would be to create the `UIDatePicker` in `viewDidAppear`. Still wondering why it takes so much time to load.